# Keras R GPU configuration is using Intel dedicated GPU, not NVIDIA Card

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I've gone through the arduous process of setting up GPU support for Keras, and it appears to have worked. Running the following code appears to confirm this:

```
> tensorflow::tf_gpu_configured()
2021-09-06 11:48:01.448811: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1510] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 3495 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
TensorFlow built with CUDA:  TRUE 
2021-09-06 11:48:01.450971: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1510] Created device /device:GPU:0 with 3495 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
GPU device name:  /device:GPU:0[1] TRUE
```

This seems to say it thinks it's using my NVIDIA card, but on my computer GPU 0 is the dedicated Intel graphics, and GPU 1 is the NVIDIA.

When I run the MNIST example model, it clearly is running on my dedicated Intel graphics:

[image]

If I crank up the model size to where it exceeds Intel's 2GB to try to force it to my NVIDIA card (6gb) I get an overflow error.

Anyone know a way to update Keras to see the NVIDIA card or what my next troubleshooting steps might be?

Comment: are you using anaconda ?

Comment: That is highly unlikely. To the best of my knowledge, intel integrated graphics simply do not support CUDA so it is impossible that this GPU is used. The code names it GPU 0 because it simply numbers _detected_ GPUs starting at 0. The low usage may be explained by the fact that the MNIST example is very simple. The usage of the integrated card may be explained by you watching YouTube videos on the side, or doing whatever else (we don't know).

Comment: Gunesh-- I downloaded miniconda as part of the setup process. I already had python running through Visual Studio Code and use pip, not conda, when working there.

Comment: try this ```with tf.device('/gpu:0'):``` replace to ```/gpu:1``` if former not working

Comment: Xdurch0-- Thanks for confirming, that was my suspicion as well. It defiantly is running on A parallelized gpu, because it's going way faster.

Comment: Gunesh-- I ran that in Python and it works fine with both 0 and 1, but I also tried "With tf.device('/gpu:7363'): and that worked fine too. So...

Comment: If you look at your tensorflow log when running code, you will see that the Intel GPU does not appear at all, same if you list GPU devices inside tensorflow.

Comment: Any potential explanations for why my Task Manager performance tab is lying to me?